# How can I hide Protected Excel AddIn Functions from Appearing in Insert Function Dialogue Box?

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I recently discovered, however, that all public functions are displayed in the "Insert Function" dialogue box when you select "User Defined" in the "Or select a category" drop down list.

This happens even if you password protect the project and lock it for viewing.

To get to the "Insert Function" dialogue box press Shift-F3.

Private functions are not displayed in the list, but it is impossible to make all functions private, especially if you want to reuse them across modules.

Is there a way to prevent public functions stored in a protected add-in from being displayed in the "Insert Function" dialogue box in Excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following code to your module will make the public functions accessible through code but will hide them in this dialog.

```
Option Private Module
```

Comment: POW! I need to learn more of those module level declarations. Thanks!