# Can a quick access toolbar button call a macro from a specific project?

Tags: vba, word-2016

The following statements include information from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-procedures-with-the-same-name).

When calling a procedure in VBA, one must make sure that the another module in the project doesn't have a procedure with the same name. If that's the case, you have to specify the module to make sure the right procedure is called, like so.

```
Sub Main() 
Module1.MyProcedure 
End Sub
```

Now, if you work with multiple projects that have procedures with the same name, you have to specify not only the module but also the project - even if the modules have unique names.

```
Sub Main() 
    [MyProject.dotm].[MyModule].Main 
End Sub
```

I have the following specific situation. In my normal.dotm, I have a procedure `main` in module `mod_x`. I created a button in my Quick Access Toolbar to call this procedure directly. It works fine.

In my myTemplate.dotm, there is also a procedure called `main` in module `mod_y`. So, when I create a document based on this template, I have access to the macros from this template as well as from normal.dotm.

Unfortunately, when pressing the button in the toolbar now, it invariably calls the main-function within `mod_y` instead of using the correct main-function from normal.dotm.

Is it possible to change this quick access toolbar button to always call the correct function from normal.dotm and no other?

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure that all applicable projects are **referenced** by the calling project.  This will make it simpler to refer to each projects' objects plus adds the ability to **prioritize** each project.

The `normal.dotm` template should already be showing in the **Project Browser** tree:

[image: img]

- Click <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>References</kbd> and we should find `Normal` already listed — and "permanently" checked (enabled).
- Click <kbd>Browse...</kbd> and change the file type drop-down to *Word Documents*, to explicitly reference one or more projects from external documents.

  [image: img]

We can set the also set the **priority** of each project we add with the Up/Down arrows.  This specifies the order in which VBA checks the references when seeking a named procedure. **Note** that *we cannot move a* `.DOCX` *project to be "above" the **`Normal`** template*...

**However**, we'll have a workaround for that in a moment, necessary so we can refer to the external procedure in question [from our toolbar] *without* *explicitly* calling it.

---

### Explicit External Calls

I have 4 subroutines named `mySub()`: two in separate `docx` file `Module1`'s, one in `Module1` of `Normal` and one in `ThisWorkbook` of `Normal`.

Each of them can be called explicitly:

```
Project_in_Document1.Module1.mySub
Project_in_Document2.Module1.mySub
Normal.ThisDocument.mySub
Normal.Module1.mySub
```

---

### Workaround: *call an external sub as if it's internal*

In the case of your toolbar, we'll need it to call a sub, something like:

```
Project_in_Document2.Module1.mySub
```

...but we can only refer to it with a *local* procedure name (which wants to "closest" one -- which is in `normal.dot`.)

**So *we cheat***, by adding another procedure by the same name, only "closer"  --  **as a local procedure in the current module**:

```
Sub mySub()
    Project_in_Document2.Module1.mySub
End Sub
```

Now when we (or a toolbar) calls **`mySub`**, Excel is directed to the intended procedure.

[image]
[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

---

### *Notes:*

We can *not* references any **Private** procedures from an outside location, so:

- They must **not** be tagged as `Private Sub` (or `Private Function`), and,
- There must **not** be a module-level declaration of `Option Private`.

---

Once all the relevant projects are referenced in the References dialog, there's an added bonus of inline definition tips as reminders of the correct syntax:

[image]

<sup>I suppose it would be a better example if I'd used a project that's *not* built-in... but you get the idea!</sup>

---

## More Information & Related Links:

- MSDN : **[References Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/references-dialog-box)** (VBA)
- Bently.com : [**Call procedure in another [microstation] project**](https://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/microstation-programming---forum/81452/vba-call-procedure-in-another-vba-project)
- VBForums : [**Calling a Sub Procedure in another VBAProject**](http://calling%20a%20sub%20procedure%20in%20one%20vbaproject%20from%20another%20vbaproject/)
- MSDN : [**Troubleshooting Broken References**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se.aspx)
- Stack Overflow : [**Re-use (but not show) Core VBA functions (UDFs) across projects**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42049718/8112776)
- MSDN : [**Migrating Word VBA Solutions to Visual Studio Tools for Office**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192482.aspx)
- MS Docs : [**How to: Customize the Quick Access Toolbar**](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/mfc/how-to-customize-the-quick-access-toolbar)
- MSDN : [**How to: Use VBA to Add a Custom Command to the Ribbon**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ee767705.aspx)

Comment: I do appreciate you taking the time to write such an extensive reply, but I still have difficulties figuring out if that's an actual answer. In the first part of your answer you describe how to override normal.dotm when I'm trying to achieve just the opposite. You go on to describe that subs in normal.dotm have preference when my exact issue is that they don't. Finally, you show how I can call subs from other projects using VBA although that was already a premise of my question.

Comment: I'm not ruling out a misunderstanding on my part, or yours. So I'll recap: normal.dotm and myTemplate.dotm have each a sub called "mySub". For the sake of argument let's assume I cannot rename either. I want the quickstart button to always call "mySub" from normal.dotm, even if I just created a new document from myTemplate.dotm. Is that possible?